# Using Spinner in a List Item does not trigger the OnItemClik

Tags: android, events, listview

I have a `ListView` in which each List item has a `Spinner`. I have successfully added an `OnItemSelectedListener` to each spinner by implementing `OnItemSelectedListener` in the `Activity` and adding it in the `GetView()` of the adapter.

The problem is, I also have to implement `OnItemClickListener` for the `ListView` in the `Activity`. I have done that, but the event is not getting fired for the Item Click on normal list items. But, it is getting fired for the list section headers(which do not have the spinners).

How can I trigger the event for the List items as well?

Comment: also add click listener for `List items` in `getView`. As `OnItemClickListener` will not fire if `a list row` have click able items as child.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this,

add the below property to your Spinner element,

```
android:focusable=false
```

The problem is because spinner is a element with clickable property, which will take the control of your click events and hence your listview wont get the chance to handle the click events. By adding the above property you can make both the spinner and your listview to get worked.

If it still doesn't work then try adding this to the top most layout of your listview element xml ,

```
android:descendantFocussability=blocksDescendants
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm! The android:focusable property for the spinner didn't work, but I added the android:descendantFocusability for the List View element and it worked beautifully! Thanks! :D

Comment: Not a problem.. Welcome always.

Comment: @AndroSelva hi, I'm getting conflict with ListView(Navigation drawer)and a Spinner in actionbar (ABC) adapter conflict when slide left right of navigation drawer calls spinners onItemSelected any tips? like how can I check AdapterView<?> view  view call is from Spinner or List view??

Comment: @AndroSelva solved it's because of invalidateOptionsMenu(); not for List view in the drawer solved this by using Runnable